# Remove vertical line from specific cell in Table

Tags: tables

I want to create the table as shown in the Image.
[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `\multicolumn` command.

Comment: @Bernard nothing because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @leandriis I did have a look (at `\multicolumn`). But did not get anything over there. Its sad that something that can be done so easily in Word becomes pain in LaTeX.

Comment: Well, the multicolumn command in its general form looks like: `\multicolumn{<number of columns>}{<format>}{<text>}`. Applied to your table, it would for example be `\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Core Courses}}`. Apart from that, please edit your question to include the code for the table you already have. With the code it is a lot easier to see where your actual problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible code, based on `tabularx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{!{\vrule width0.8pt}c|c|>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}X|c|c|c!{\vrule width0.8pt}}
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
  \thead{S. No}& \thead{Course\\No} & \thead{Course Title} & thead{Sem/Year} & \thead{Credit} & \thead{Grade}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \multicolumn{6}{!{\vrule width0.8pt}l!{\vrule width0.8pt}}{\bfseries Core Courses}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \multicolumn{6}{!{\vrule width0.8pt}l!{\vrule width0.8pt}}{\bfseries Elective Courses}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \multicolumn{6}{!{\vrule width0.8pt}l!{\vrule width0.8pt}}{\bfseries Compulsory Courses / Optional Courses}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\ \hline
     & & & & & \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]